# How to detect calls while app is in the background?

Tags: windows-phone-8

So I understand that a foreground app can detect phone calls by registering for the obscured event, but while my app is running in the background, playing sound, sending notifications, etc, it does not hit the same event.

Is there a specific way to handle phone calls in this circumstance? The obscured event is the only one that I can find for detecting phone calls, but it won't work in this instance.

Comment: What problem are you tryign to solve? I believe the OS interrupts background media players for the call for you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, with the current API there isn't...

In fact, I'd say that the obscured event can't even be considered a reliable way to detect an incoming phone call: you can use it right now for that purpose, but tomorrow Microsoft can just go ahead and add new stuff that will raise that very same event!